# jQuery .remove() won't remove element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, removechild

I'm trying to dynamically remove `li` elements from an HTML page, I'm using the `.remove()` method but, if I inspect the HTML page I can see that the element is NOT removed, it has simply changed his visibility to `display: none;`. 
Is there a way I can DEFINITIVELY remove the element from the page?

this is the snippet (I clone a `li` from `#ul1` and append it to `#ul2`):

```
var oggettoClone = $(this).clone();
oggettoClone.appendTo("#ul2");

$(oggettoClone).bind({
    click: function(o) {

        var r = confirm("Remove this element?");
        if (r == true) 
        {
            $(this).slideUp();

            setTimeout(function(){
                $(this).remove();
            }, 2000);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: can you reproduce it in a www.jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: .remove() does what it says on the tin, it removes the element from the DOM tree, and everything that was inside it as well.

Comment: Inspect in View source, correct ?

Comment: If that's the case, it seems `.remove()` has been redefined in your application to be equivalent to `.hide()`.

Comment: can you verify HOW you are inspecting the HTML page?

Comment: right click with the mouse and "Inspect element"

Comment: ah, thanks for the code update - setTimeout is your issue; that tends to cause problems when you use $(this) inside the scope of the setTimeout.

Comment: slideUp() is hiding the element and remove doesn't work because scope is incorrect

Comment: THANK YOU, I removed setTimeout and everything went well! But is there a way I can obtain the same effect? Because I need to SLIDE UP the element and remove it. If I remove it without "setTimeout", it will disappear without the "cool effect"!

Comment: Whenever you are getting crazy results like this - try console.log($(this));

A lot of times, the "this" reference is different than you think (like in this case), so you can nip that problem in the bud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because you are calling `$(this)` inside the setTimeout sub-function. You need to define the element as a variable to access it inside a sub-function.

```
$(oggettoClone).bind({
    click: function(o) {
        var r = confirm("Remove this element?");
        var t = $(this);
        if (r == true) {
            $(t).slideUp();
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(t).remove();
            }, 2000);
        }

    }
});
```

or follow andi's advice and use [`.sideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)'s callback option:

```
$(oggettoClone).bind({
    click: function(o) {
        var r = confirm("Remove this element?");
        if (r == true) {
            $(this).slideUp(function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the "complete" callback function of slideUp
( http://api.jquery.com/slideup/ )

```
$(this).slideUp(function(){
    // this part will execute when slideUp is complete.
    $(this).remove();
});
```